# Broadcom BCM94352HMB wifi card not working

Tags: wifi, network-interface, broadcom

As mentioned above, I got an BCM94352HMB wifi card in my laptop but it does not work (it's not recognized) under pretty new linux kernels (arch linux).
So does somebody know if there is support for this card under linux (and how to enable it) ?

It would be unfortunate it that would not be the case because I had to go back to Windows then.

**EDIT**: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` outputs

> 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
>       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2154]
>       Kernel driver in use: wl

Comment: Did you try the links given on [wikidevi](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Broadcom_BCM94352HMB)?

Comment: Well, I also found that article before asking that question here, but the links in the driver section on this page are useless since they are all for windows.

Comment: The AUR links are for Windows??

Comment: What, I did not see any AUR links. Ah, on the right side, gonna try them out and say whether it worked or not.

Comment: @Gilles Works now after installing "broadcom-w-dkms" from the official repo. However, the driver seems poor since I am not able to create a WiFi hotspot, for example via the "create_ap" script from the AUIR, whose execution lead to the output "Your adapter does not support AP (master) mode".

Comment: Please edit and add the output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 `

Comment: OK, did that. Output is in the OP.

Comment: "had to go back to Windows then". It's possible to buy a different wifi card. Did this one come with the laptop?

Comment: Nope bought that card cuz it's compatible with OS X. But I won't plug that old Intel card in cause it's has less features.